# Let $p$ be a prime. When is $p+1$ twice a square number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p+1$ is itself a square number, it is easy to conclude that $p=3$: $p+1=m^2 \implies p = (m+1)(m-1)$ and from here it's easy to see that $m=2$. However, I don't see how a similar process could be done with $2n^2$ (factoring into two integers by using the difference of two squares).

I have tested a few values of $p$, namely $p=2,3,5, \dots 41$ and checked that $p=7,17,31$ were the only ones that worked out of these. But I believe that there are infinite solutions.

Also, I wonder if there's a nice way to find the solutions for $p+1=dn^2$ where $d$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: What do you mean by "a similar process with $2n^2$"? What does the $2n^2$ replace?

Comment: $241$ works, $\frac {241+1}2=11^2$.  And $647$, and $881$

Comment: Should say:  the [Bunyakovsky Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) would tell us that $2x^2-1$ should take infinitely many prime values.  Of course, no non-linear example of that conjecture is yet known.

Comment: The conjecture is also stated in https://oeis.org/A066436

Comment: Numbers of the form $18k^2-1$ are $1$ less than twice a perfect square and have the form $6n-1$ which includes many primes.: $17, 71, 449, 647, 881, 1151, 2591, 3041, 3527, 4049,\dots$ It is a curious fact that all but three ($449, 647, 3041$) of that limited list are also the smaller of a twin prime pair!

Comment: Numbers of the form $6k+1$ that are $1$ less that twice a perfect square require $3k+1=n^2 \Rightarrow 3n=k^2-1=(k-1)(k+1)$. So if we pick pairs of numbers that are different by $2$ and have one of the pair divisible by $3$, we can generate many candidates: $7,31,49,97,127,199,241,337,\dots$ Of this short list, only $49$ is not a prime number. I note also that many of these are the larger of a twin prime pair. This and my previous comment show that there are many numbers satisfying the conditions, but do not answer whether there are infinitely many.

Comment: $$p\equiv 1,7\pmod 8$$ for a start.

Comment: In fact 1,7,15 modulo 16

Comment: Modulo 18 we get 13,7,1, and 17